# Validacion de un select o un insert

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo un problema al momento de sacar que puntos se encuentran dentro de mi mapa para validarlos , ya he creado poligonos y tambien ingresado puntos y se que con `ST_CONTAINS` se puede obtener que puntos estan dentro de un poligono , lo que deseo es solo que mi ultimo ingreso de un punto muestre si esta dentro o fuera del poligono .
Encontré algunas soluciones unas puede a travez de un `select` o sino antes da hacerle un `insert` e ingresar el punto por ejemplo la siguiente

```
SELECT nombre , case ST_CONTAINS(geometria, punto)
WHEN 0 THEN 'N'
WHEN 1 THEN 'S' 
END AS contenido, 
idmensaje 
AS ID
FROM mensaje , mapa
```

Con lo que obtengo los siguientes datos

```
nombre     contenido   ID
Poligono1      N        1
Poligono1      S        2
Poligono1      N        3
Poligono2      S        1
Poligono2      N        2
Poligono2      N        3
Poligono3      N        1
Poligono3      N        2
Poligono3      N        3
```

Demostrando que el punto con ID 1 pertence al poligono 2 y el ID 2 pertence al poligono 1 mientras que el ultimo ingresado el ID N3 no pertenece a ninguno y por tanto no esta dentro de los poligonos .

Lo que deseo si se puede con esto es solo que muestre mi ultimo ingreso si se encuentra o no dentro de los poligonos , probe con `DESC LIMIT 1` y también con  `max(idmensaje)` se que ambos pueden mostrar la ultima fila pero el problema es que no es la solucion .
Lo que deseo que salga.

```
 Ultimopuntoingresado       Mensaje
 ID3                        Fuera de algun poligono
```

Si ingreso otro punto y se encuentra dentro de cualquier poligono

```
 Ultimopuntoingresado       Mensaje
 ID3                        Dentro de un poligono
```

Agradezco si alguien pueda ayudarme a encontrar una solución talvez lo complique mucho y esta mas sencilla la respuesta, muchas gracias ante todo .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para el dataset que propones, independientemente de cómo hayas llegado hasta él:

```
CREATE TABLE puntos(
  nombre varchar(15),
  contenido varchar(1),
  ID int
  );
INSERT INTO puntos (nombre, contenido, ID) VALUES
  ('Poligono1','N',1),
  ('Poligono1','S',2),
  ('Poligono1','N',3),
  ('Poligono2','S',1),
  ('Poligono2','N',2),
  ('Poligono2','N',3),
  ('Poligono3','N',1),
  ('Poligono3','N',2),
  ('Poligono3','N',3);
```

Te propongo la siguiente solución:

```
SELECT CONCAT('ID',(
    SELECT MAX(ID) FROM puntos
  )) Ultimopuntoingresado,IF(
    COUNT(*)>0,
    'Dentro de un polígono',
    'Fuera de un polígono'
  ) Mensaje
  FROM puntos WHERE ID=(
    SELECT MAX(ID) FROM puntos
  ) AND contenido='S';
```

De la que se obtiene un resultado como el que comentas:

> ```
> Ultimopuntoingresado  Mensaje
> ID3                   Fuera de un polígono
> ```

Confírmame en los comentarios si es lo que necesitas y qué dudas te plantea para detallar lo que te resulte confuso.

Comment: Hola David , muchas gracias por el apoyo y si me ayuda la solución porque si me da el resultado pero mi problema es que quiero que el resultado solo necesite de una sentencia , agregándole la ultima solución creo que tendría que crear una tabla nueva a través de select del dataset que eh creado y  usar la solución y después eliminar la tabla y volver a ejecutarlo y eso es mas complicado . Agradezco tu ayuda buscare la manera de insertar la sentencia solución dentro de la principal para no hacer dos ejecuciones .

Comment: ¿Te has planteado encapsularlo en una función o un procedimiento almacenado? ¿Por qué necesitas que sea una query única?

Comment: sii agradezco tu apoyo use `CREATE TABLE` para crear una nueva tabla y luego `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS` dentro de un proceso para borrarlo y no aparezca un error al momento de realizar la consulta me sirvió la solución que me pasaste muchas gracias.